# Optimization problem (Sum of distances)

Tags: functions, optimization

Given an ordered sequence $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \cdots \leq x_n $  of length $n$
and a cost function $C(i) = \sum_{j}^{n}{\left|x_i-x_j\right|}$.

The goal is to minimize the cost function.
How do you prove that $C(k)$ always returns the optimum, where $k$ is the median of $x$?

Comment: Your notation looks strange: the argument of $C$ is written as index $i$, but later you plug in $m$, which is a value and not an index.